# How to restore this 1mb sql dump?

Tags: shell, postgresql

I've got 1mb of sql that I dumped with `pg_dump`, looks like

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET escape_string_warning = off;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: app_address; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: me; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE app_address (

...
```

Now I'm trying to restore it. [The docs say](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/backup.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE) I can use I can use

```
psql dbname < infile
```

But that tells me

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "me", database "mydb", SSL off
```

Why's that? How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I rountinely experience being unable to restore a sql dump unless I supply a username, so try:

```
psql -U <username> <database> < <infile>
```

Comment: Actually, I couldn't. You answered too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure pg_hba.conf so you are allowed to access the database.

Adding this line to pg_hba.conf should do the trick (I think):

```
host    all             all             localhost               trust
```